# SSIS Sending MSMQ message to remote Server Private Queue

Tags: ssis, msmq, nservicebus

I am new to SSIS . I am trying to send a MSMQ text message to a ***Remote Private*** MSMQ Queue.

I have the following questions

1. What should be the path for the remote private queue in the MSMQ Connection Manager?

   1. I tried using `XYZ\private$\remoteprivatequeue` where *XYZ* is the machine name for the remote server and "*remoteprivatequeue*" is the name of the queue.
2. It is possible that the permissions on the remote server MSMQ queues might be incorrect, How should I  identify that it is indeed a permissions problem
3. The private queues were created by NServiceBus (hence the NServiceBus tag to the question), Does this affect the queues in any way. I get the following error on both my local and remote servers when I go to

> Computer Management  -> Services and Applications -> Message Queuing 
>                                                     -> (right click)Properties 
>                                                     -> Security Tab

Error :

> The security descriptor cannot be obtained.
>   Error : This operation is not supported for Message Queuing installed in workgroup mode

I tried sending the message to a private queue on my local machine where I get the same error *on clicking the properties tab* described above but posting the message **works**!!

I tried using the task mentioned here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403349.aspx but got connection errors.

Edit :

I get the following error when I test the Connection when using the format `XYZ\private$\remoteprivatequeue`

```
Program Location:

   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, Boolean throwException)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(String path)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.MsmqConnectionManagerForm.buttonTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the format name when talking to those queues:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=TCP: IPAddress\QueueName
FormatName:DIRECT=OS: MachineName\QueueName
```